# Plone novice: Site appears unstyled instead of Sunburst

Tags: plone

My site used the Sunburst theme without any custom style sheets – at most I would update the logo. I recently updated the logo and front-page after a long absence.  The logo was successfully updated, however something else happened and now the site appears unstyled. Skip to content/Skip to navigation text links (for accessibility) appear at the top where they had not previously.

I checked portal_skins/custom, but there was no ploneCustom.css file there to remove, only the logo.png. I tried changing the theme to Classic but it also appeared unstyled, so then I changed it back to Sunburst. Next I went to portal_skins/sunburst_styles and pressed the customize button for public.css and ploneCustom.css, hoping to override the current style. Even though the style files were copied to portal_skins/custom (I did not modify the copies), the site still appears unstyled.

Please help a grad student whose occasional task is to maintain a Plone site (server is running Plone 4.) The server admin is away at a conference – the previous server admin who had the Plone expertise graduated last fall and is now out of the country (and also at the same conference.) I’ve read the documentations and searched for similar issues, but am at wit’s end.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance in how to revert back to the default Sunburst theme styles!

Comment: Does "Unstyled" mean that it appears to have no CSS, or that the style looks different (I like Plone 2 or so?)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the "Plone Classic Theme" seems to become applied when upgrading. In the Theme control panel ( `http://yoursite/@@skins-controlpanel` ) make sure that "Sunburst" is selected.

Comment: Thanks for your response. By "unstyled", the site had no CSS styles applied - so menu bar items appeared in an unordered list instead of a horizontal navigation bar with background colors. It almost seemed like it was stuck in accessibility mode (as in Section 508-compliant), judging from the navigation text links.

Comment: I set the site theme to Classic Plone, then back to Sunburst (logging out completely & restarting browser/flushing cache each time). Now the site is correctly displaying the Sunburst theme. Thank you again!

Comment: @user2278083: OK, haven't seen that effect before, but glad it helped!